# Quartz datasource and existing connection pool with a one database

Tags: java, datasource, quartz-scheduler, connection-pooling

This question might look too broad, but I could not find a solution or any idea from existing sources in the web. There might not be exact answers for this, what I need is your suggestions on how to get this implemented.

My application has its own datasource for CRUD operations. Plus I have a new micro service to execute scheduled jobs. The idea is to maintain only a single database for both the services.

The existing service has been configured to use a connection pool for its db transactions. properties like max number of active datasources, max idle datasources at a given time etc have been configured for that service.

Now, my question is about maintaining the pool when quartz connects to the same database to query its own tables. At first place, is this possible? or is it always better to keep a separate database for quartz tables. Or Else, can I configure these two services to access same database flawlessly by doing configurations? (Remember that these two db operations happen in two separate microservices)

Comment: Yes its possible to point both quartz and your microservice to the same database. We have a similar set up running in production. As to whether its a good idea to have a separate database , it depends on your use case like is quartz running lighter load / you have a batch heavy use case, your availability requirements etc.. Also quartz will use its own connection pool..

Comment: it might be helpful to you: https://www.candidjava.com/tutorial/quartz-reuse-existing-data-source-connection-pool/